# Why simple accessor can not found? (Key-Value Coding )

Tags: ios, key-value, key-value-coding

I'm just working on parsing JSON file, so my question is simple accessor can not found? As from official documentation of key value coding says

> Search Pattern for the Basic Setter .
>   "Look for the first accessor named set: or _set, in that
>   order. If found, invoke it with the input value (or unwrapped value,
>   as needed) and finish."

so simple accessor is a method what respondsToSelector tries to find. it seems that setValueforkey always using simple accessor. so why it can not be found? and is simple accessor creates by setvalueforkey method? because i didn't create by myself nontheless debug info shows responds to selector true
[image]

Comment: Is the class a subclass of `NSObject`? Because KVO only works with subclasses of `NSObject`.

Comment: Yes it is. This is not a problem , I did not receive any error I just confused about this question